# Django accepts an integer into a CharField

Tags: python, django-forms

I am learning django and created a `Page form class` like so:

```
from django import forms

class Page(forms.Form):
    title  = forms.CharField(max_length = 200, min_length = 10)
    body   = forms.CharField(min_length = 200, max_length = 8000)
    author = forms.CharField(min_length = 5, max_length   = 60)
    price  = forms.FloatField(min_value = 10, max_value   = 50)
```

I fiddled with it in the interactive shell and found out that when I enter an `integer`, it simply accepts and validates all the fields although it did convert the `integer` to `string` first.

Isn't it plainly problematic? I mean I would not want any digit or any symbol in the `Author field`. Do I need to write my additional `clean_author method` or do I have any other `django Form class` at my disposal to address exactly this issue??

Comment: Djang CharField accepts bool, int, str, float as valid datatype. For other type it'll throw a error of 'Not a valid string' as of [Github link](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/374c0d414237708a28eccc412c078c06d0d82be2/rest_framework/fields.py#L801)

Answer (score 1):

There is no field type that will validate that kind of data.

You can easily validate the data enter by users using regular Expressions on backend or the frontend.

```
exp = '[\w\s]+'
```

This will only accept words and whitespaces which is perfect for author name

https://regexr.com/ use this site to make your regular expression.

Comment: Are you sure there is no field type for this problem. I believe this is such a commonplace issue that django must have some magic method or keyword parameter to the existing methods. I am wondering if there is any.

Comment: I am pretty sure there isn't. But even if there is, this is quit an easy problem that can be fixed with two lines of code in the backend.